# In a polynomial ring $R = {\mathbb C}[x]$, let $p(x) , q(x) \in R$, is it true that multiplication of $(p(x))(q(x))$ equals their intersection?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In a polynomial ring $R = {\mathbb C}[x]$, let $p(x) , q(x) \in R$, is it true $\bigl(  p(x) q(x) \bigr) = \bigl( p(x) \bigr) \cap \bigl( q(x) \bigr)$?

I think it is not, since if $R$ is a commutative ring, and $I, J$ are two ideals, and $I+J=R$ then $IJ=I\cap J$.

Here although polynomial is communicative ring, but $p, q$ are just two arbitrary element of R, so the title need not to be true, but I cannot think of a counterexample. Any help, thanks!

Comment: Consider the case $q(x)=p(x)$

Comment: LCM of $a$ and $b$ equals (or is associated to) $ab$ iff $1$ (and hence every unit) is a GCD of $a$ and $b$ (and then $a$ and $b$ would be called "coprime" or "relatively prime"). This is true in any UFD.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Sorry, I haven't learned ufd and pid yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideal $(p(x))\cdot (q(x))$ is generated by the product of $p(x)$ and $q(x)$, while the ideal $(p(x))\cap (q(x))$ is generated by the least common multiple of $p(x)$ and $q(x)$. These are equal if and only if $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are coprime (that is, they share no divisors).

So a counterexample would be $p(x)=q(x)$.

Comment: ... with $\deg(p) \ge 1$. (Sorry for being pedantic.)